# C# - How to make FormUrlEncodedContent from more level JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, http

I neet to make `FormUrlEncodedContent` from this http request body json:

```
{
    "number": 123456,
    "names": {
        "firstName": "a",
        "secondName": "b",
        "age": 10
    }
}
```

I can make it just from "one level" json like this:

```
 FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("number", "123"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "John")
            });
```

but I really dont know how to make next levels. I want it for POST request.

**UPDATE:**

I use it to connect to NodeJs server. There is this control:

```
const {number, names} = this.request.body;

    if (!number|| !names|| !names.firstName|| !names.secondName|| !names.age)
```

Comment: What kind of API is this being sent to? Is it being sent to another dotnet service or a different external API? Different kinds of services allow different deserialization methods. For instance, in some API's you might send a key named `names.firstName` with a value of `a`, others might now allow it altogether.

Comment: @KyleGoode its for REST Api service from NodeJS server. I use HttpClient for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending this to a ASP.NET MVC service or WebAPI service then the standard model binder is able to deserialize a request that is sent like this:

```
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("number", "123"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "John"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("names.firstName", "a"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("names.secondName", "b"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("names.age", "10"),
            });
```

Another convention I see often (that will not work with the default model binder in ASP.NET MVC or WebAPI) is to do something like this:

```
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("number", "123"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", "John"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("names[firstName]", "a"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("names[secondName]", "b"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("names[age]", "10"),
            });
```

Comment: It is not for ASP.NET, it is for for REST Api from NodeJS server. I use HttpClient for it.

Comment: I have edited the question. Your solution has problem with !names control.